# Sending form data from one server to another

Tags: php, forms, email, post, get

I have a class project. Its not really REQUIRED but it would help my other class members understand how forms work. Its a HTML & CSS class. I only took the class to get the prerequs out of the way for better classes.

Now for this class my school doesn't allow the students to have access to ANY php so my classmates cant make their own contact form. At least not one that will work.

So my question is, is it possible for me to create the "mail.php" script on my server and have them send it FROM the school server TO my web server. Then from my web server it will handle the data and send the email. I know this is a possible security hole but the people in this class aren't very computer savvy anyway. So would I do this via a post or get? Or do I have to use something a little more involved?

Comment: just put the action on their form as a url to your page.  You could do either get or post

Comment: So that would work then? Because I was thinking of doing that but I wasnt sure. Thanks!

Comment: CORS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) restrictions do not apply to requests originating from a native HTML form. They are only enforced on requests generated in JavaScript.

Comment: Ill give that a shot but only problem is the classmates arent very good with the whole javascript stuff. So I think ill just have to let things be and say I cant do it lol

Comment: it is not javascript.  He was saying that javascript has cross-domain policies.  What you are doing will work just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to just point the action to your classmate's page.

```
<form action='http://yourfriendsserver.com/receiver.php">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It ended up working. my webserver was just alittle slow today